# How do I create an IEventProcessor on Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, azure-eventhub

I am exploring ways to use Azure Event Hubs with Azure Service Fabric and plan on running an IEventProcessor in a service. How how do I structure the code for such a service?

Comment: have you seen this? https://github.com/khenidak/service-fabric-eventhub-listener

Comment: Thx, I'll look into that!

Comment: @LoekD is there any reason to map Event Hubs partitions on SF partitions? Can you give an example where it could be better than having only one SF *stateless* service without partitions, that will process events from Event Hubs and call methods with particular partitions of other *statefull* services?

Comment: @cassandrad The reason you want a _stateful_ service is to keep track of where you're up to in the stream of events (Event Hubs call it _checkpointing_). The reason you want partitions is to distribute the load if you have looots of events.

Comment: @LoekD I have trouble getting the sample working. One thing I was wondering about is where the partitions are stored in this case. I have previously looked at examples where they are stored in Azure Storage Account.

Comment: @getpsyched The partitions of `EventHub` are queried in the `StartAsync` operation of EventHubListener.cs. For every partition an instance of `EventHubListenerPartitionReceiver` is created. Each of those has (indirect) access to a Stateful Services' StateManager.